# Visual Studio 2017 File icons broken

Tags: icons, visual-studio-2017

I have a weird issue with my visual studio 2017. When I load a project the icons look just fine, but when I edit and save some code the icon disappears.

It looks like this:

[image]

The issue isn't breaking, it's just odd that it's broken. I have used the installer to 'repair' my visual studio, but to no avail. Has this happened to anyone else?

Edit: Some backstory might be needed. I have reset this laptop at the start of a new school year. Visual Studio 2015 has worked fine (Including the icons) before I reset the laptop.

After the reset, I had installed Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise edition, since someone stated my school had a license. Since they did not, I uninstalled it and installed Visual Studio 2017 Professional edition. The icons have been broken ever since I installed this version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is reported by the developer's community [Solution Shows Missing File Icon](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/80855/solution-shows-missing-file-icon.html).

And now this issue has been fixed in version 15.4 which has been released a new visual studio after solving it. You can download fixed version of visual studio from below link:

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/

Comment: I was unaware of that, installing as I'm typing this. Will award the bounty if this resolves the issue

Comment: It works now, I have to wait 20 hours before I can award you the bounty. Will do so when SO lets me. Thanks!